# How to find if an object of a class with same data already exists in a NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c

I apologize for this basic question, but I am 2-month new to obj-c.

**Problem:**
I am not able to find if an object with same data already exists in the NSMutableArray.

**What I am doing?**

```
ScanDigInfoForTable* sfile = [[ScanDigInfoForTable alloc]init];        
sfile.data = "myData";


int inde = [_DataList indexOfObject:sfile] ;        
if(inde == -1)
    [_DataList addObject:sfile];

ScanDigInfoForTable* sfile2 = [[ScanDigInfoForTable alloc]init];        
sfile2.data = "myData";


inde = [_DataList indexOfObject:sfile2] ;        
if(inde == -1)
    [_DataList addObject:sfile2];
```

**Issue:**
The _DataList get 2 objects instead of 1. Many thanks in advance for your attention.

S.P: I already know that I may traverse the whole array in a loop in order to check the data already exists. Looking for a better solution as the array may have thousands of records.

Comment: `indexOfObject` does not return -1 for objects that are not part of the collection, it returns `NSNotFound`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, comparing two custom objects is really not that simple for the simple fact there is no defined way to declare equality. It is individual choice to define the rules for equality for the objects they are creating.

In your case, it would be two step process:

**Step 1:** Implement `isEqual:` in your `ScanDigInfoForTable` class. Assuming `ScanDigInfoForTable` is a model class and that it has three string properties - `code`, `data` & `itemID` (you can have any type).

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(ScanDigInfoForTable *)other {
    return [self.code isEqualToString:other.code] && [self.data isEqualToString:other.data] && [self.itemID isEqualToString:other.itemID];
}
```

**Step 2:** Call `containsObject:` method on `NSMutableArray`. This method would internally call `isEqual:` to give you the results based on the rules you defined.

```
// If the object does not exist in the list, we add it

if (![_DataList containsObject:sfile2]) {
    [_DataList addObject:sfile2];
}
```

Comment: `if ([_DataList containsObject:sfile2])` is missing a !

Comment: I am sorry but I did not get what you meant @Willeke

Answer (score 2):

In Objective-C object equality is determined by the methods `-isEqual:` and `-hash`.

When testing object membership in a collection the items of the collection are sent `isEqual:`. The default implementation only compares the addresses of objects, which is why you are seeing duplicates. Your objects do no provide their own implementation of equality based on the data they contain.

To fix this you can override `isEqual:` to compare objects based on the data they represent. Using your example in your question, this could just be:

```
- (BOOL) isEqual:(id)object {
    BOOL result = N0;
    if (object != self){
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[self class]]){
            result = [[self data] isEqual:[(ScanDigInfoForTable *)object data]];
        }
    } else {
      result = YES;
    }
    return result;
}
```

[Mike Ash](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html) has a great article about implementing equality. In general, if you are implementing a custom class you should make equality a part of that.

Answer (score -1):

You can user `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` for example

```
NSArray * matches = [_DataList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:
                    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"data == %@ ",sfile2.data]];
if(matches.count == 0) {
    [_DataList addObject:sfile2];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
 NSMutableSet* set1 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array1];
 NSMutableSet* set2 = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:array2];
 [set1 intersectSet:set2]; //this will give you only the obejcts that are in both sets

 NSArray* result = [set1 allObjects];
```

This has the benefit of not looking up the objects in the array, while looping through another array, which has N^2 complexity.

and also set2 doesn't have to be mutable, might as well use just

```
 NSSet* set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:array2];
```

Comment: That will only work if the class implements `isEqual`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate how can I use it in my scenario as I only have 1 NSMutable array. Many pardons for the ignorance

Comment: in your case you can use NSPredicate or below is simple solution to find duplicate objects index in an array

Comment: NSArray *array=@[@"one",@"one",@"one",@"two",@"two",@"four",@"four",@"four"];
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
 {
     if ([obj isEqualToString:@"one"])
     {
         NSLog(@"index %d",idx);

     }
 }];